# fabric for "tree" like deployments

Tags: python, deployment, fabric

i am trying to get my head around fabric.

we have different machines:

```
                      +--+ b2b (+config)            
       +------+ api --+                    
       |              +--+ b2c (+config)             
       |                                   
       |              +---+ service1 (+config)
       |              |                    
       |              +---+ service2 (+config)
all +---------+ web --+                    
       |              +---+ service3 (+config)        
       |              |                    
       |              +---+ service4 (+config)            
       |                                   
       |                                   
       +------+ db (+config)
```

from the commandline i want to achieve something like this:

```
fab -R prod prepare:all
```

here -R prod defines the user and target hosts, something like this:

```
'prod':
        {
            'user': 'some_prod_user',
            'hosts': ['some_prod_host1', 'some_prod_host2']
        }
```

this map is treated like a configuration and attached to each node.

now when i execute this command i want that node "all" calls all it's children, and they call their children until all have execute the task prepare.

```
fab -R prod prepare:api.b2b
```

should only prepare the b2b node, nothing more.

i've already build the whole thing in python (object hierarchy) and so on.

the problem: how can i build the whole 'env' dictionary when each sub class is running it's 'prepare' method.

according to the execution model the whole 'env.host_string' is already built up as soon as i reach the subclasses and i can't redefine them.

so this leaves me thinking - is fabric the right tool for me?

any help highly appreciated.

cheers
marcel

**EDIT**

looks like it could try something like:

```
all
prepare.sh
execute.sh
 - api
   prepare.sh -> calls [b2b|bc2]/prepare.sh
   execute.sh -> calls [b2b|bc2]/execute.sh
   - b2b
     fabfile.py
     prepare.sh -> invokes fab
     execute.sh -> invokes fab
   - b2c
     fabfile.py
     prepare.sh -> invokes fab
     execute.sh -> invokes fab
 - web
   prepare.sh
   execute.sh -> invokes fab
   - service1
     fabfile.py
     prepare.sh -> invokes fab
     execute.sh -> invokes fab
   - service2
     fabfile.py
     prepare.sh -> invokes fab
     execute.sh -> invokes fab
 ... you get the idea
```

now i am able to call prepare.sh on the top level and cascade down the child chain. each child calls all sub modules prepare.sh. i am also able to call each node seperately.

what do you think?

marcel

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would recommend having a single entry point such that a single `fab` command line will do whatever you want. It may be comprised of a bunch of different `task`s and `argument`s to those `task`s, but would generally be a single command line nonetheless.

What I generally do is the following:

1. Define a `task` representing the definition of the environment for each machine
2. Define a `task` representing each action I want to take
3. (Optionally) define `task`s that define `groupings` of sorts, i.e. **service**, which in turn invokes all the `task`s for your service machines, switching out the environment in between each one.

In that way, you can use a single `fab` command to specify a variety of combinations, since every environment and action is itself a `task`, which is really the primary unit off which `Fabric` works (and is essentially just a Python function around which there is a framework that helps with remote execution, etc.).

The `fab` command would then become a combination of: `fab <env1> <task1> <task2> <env2> <task1> <task2>` etc.

You could weave your hierarchy into the concept, as well, I would think, based on a `grouping task` of sorts like the **service** one I mentioned above.

**Question:** What is it that **prepare.sh** and **execute.sh** are doing?